# run mysql commands through ssh

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse, ssh

I have a set up where I automate log checking on a remote server. I have created methods like this which use the exec command to tail logs like this..

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh <user>@<domain> tail -f /location/logs
```

I print the logs to my terminal where I can run regex patterns to make sure they are correct.

Now I need to check some of the entries in the logs against some mysql tables which are also on the server. I have set up a similar method using a List to execute a series of commands to return the entries in the mysql table:

```
List<String> cmd = Arrays.asList("ssh user@domain mysql -u user -ppassword -h ipaddress", "use database", "SELECT column1, column2, etc FROM database");
    Process dumpcapProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd.toArray(new String[]{}));

    String line;
    // Reading the InputStream stream 
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dumpcapProcess.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);

    }

    // Reading the error stream for debug
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dumpcapProcess.getErrorStream()));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
```

But it doesnt work. I have played around with the syntax of the exec strings to look like this:

```
List<String> cmd = Arrays.asList("ssh", "user@domain", "mysql", "-u",  "user", "-ppassword", "-h", "ipAddress", "use databases", "SELECT columns FROM database");
```

and now i I get this error:

> Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
>     -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
>     -I, --help          Synonym for -?
>     --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
>                         'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
>                         and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
>                         --disable-auto-rehash.
>                         (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
>     -A, --no-auto-rehash 
>                         No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
>                         table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
>                         mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.
>     --auto-vertical-output 
>                         Automatically switch to vertical output mode if the
>                         result is wider than the terminal width.
>     -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.
>                         (Enables --silent.)
>     --bind-address=name IP address to bind to.
>     --character-sets-dir=name 
>                         Directory for character set files.
>     --column-type-info  Display column type information.
>     -c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server. The
>                         default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
>                         with --comments.

How can I run the mysql commands to return the result to my eclipse terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the query directly from command line using the `-e` argument. Example:

```
 mysql -uuser -ppass -hhost -Ddatabase -e'show tables'
```

This is untested, but it should be something like:

```
List<String> cmd = Arrays.asList(
    "ssh",
    "user@domain",
    "mysql",
    "-uuser",
    "-ppassword",
    "-h10.0.0.1",
    "-Ddb",
    "-e'SELECT columns FROM table'"
);
```

Comment: thanks. To use multiple queries can you use for example -e'use database'  -e'SELECT column1 FROM database'.       I tried but could only get one query to be executed

Comment: what you have works great, I figured out that multiple queries can be run from the same -e command separated by a ';'  ........ "-e'use database; SELECT * FROM database'"

Comment: @DanielCohen Note that I have selected the database with the `-D` argument. You can also execute queries without explicitly "using" a database: `SELECT * from database.table`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Problem is that there is no space between the -p and the password. You should try to build your command like this:

```
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name
```

For more informations here is the documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html